# Going through day, month and year on VBA DTPicker using TAB

Tags: vba, calendar, datetimepicker, setfocus, tab-ordering

On my userform with a calendar users can quickly navigate through all inputfields with the TAB order. That also works for the DTPicker insofar that the focus is set on the DTPicker first element = Day (I have format dd/MM/yyyy). However, after entering the day and pressing TAB the focus is on the next TextBox instead of the Month of the DTPicker.

Is there a way to use keyboard to set focus on MM after entering dd and on yyyy after entering MM? Or that after entering the day the cursos automatically moves to month and then to year?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not using the tab key, but once that control has focus, arrow keys can be used to move between day/month/year.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that out already but that's not what I was looking for. Particularily looking for either the option with TAB or where the cursor moves automaticaly from day to month and then year. For now I made a workaround by replacing the DTPicker with 3 comboboxes, but that not a very pretty solution :P

Comment: I understand what you are looking for, but there is no simple solution.